# date picker not working in angularjs ng-template script

Tags: angularjs, ng-template

I used a pop-over to show some details. I need a datepicker in that, but script is not working.

```
<div class="container" style="height:auto;">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="abc.html">
       <div class="input-group date" id="datepicker">
          <input class="form-control"  name="startDate" ng-model="startDate" name="startDate"></input>
          <span class="input-group-addon" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
       </div>
    </script>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
              format:"dd-M-yyyy",
              changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
            beforeShowDay: unavailable
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: There are many questions. Why is the picker wrapped around script tag. and why the id is "datepicker1" and you are using $("#datepicker"). And I think datepicker should be added to input, not div.

Comment: sorry my mistake the id is datepicker only

Answer (score 0):

I think there shouldn't be any tags in script tag. And the datepicket should be added to input. Try this.

```
 <div class="container" style="height:auto;">
    <script type="text/ng-template" id="abc.html"></script>
       <div class="input-group date" >
          <input class="form-control" id="datepicker" name="startDate" ng-model="startDate" name="startDate"></input>
          <span class="input-group-addon" >
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
          </span>
       </div>

</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#datepicker').datepicker({
              format:"dd-M-yyyy",
              changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
            beforeShowDay: unavailable
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: The code has to be within script tag otherwise it is not displaying only. Other thing is if you give id inside input tag also its not working.